# Run Spring Boot Application with 2nd datasource down

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.15, HikariCP 3.2.0 and 2 Databases, MSSQL and Oracle.
Then the jdbc string of credentials in yml file are correct, application starts successfully. Also if connection fails during application work it also works good and just automatically reconnect to database then it is possible. But i need to be available to start app if 2nd Oracle database is down or something like that. So, then i change jdbc string for that and try to start application it fails with

> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool:

I search network and found different HikariCP properties or spring.datasource properties and try them, but it didnt help. 
Could you please help me the solutuion for this issue.

I configure it using yml file:

```
spring:
    datasource:
      driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      url: jdbc:sqlserver:***
      username: ***
      password: ***
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      show-sql: true
      properties:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
      database: default
    jackson:
      date-format: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat
logging:
  config: classpath:logback-remote.xml
  file: /usr/share/tomcat/app.log
pqa:
  integration:
    datasource:
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      url: jdbc:oracle:***
      username: ***
      password: ***
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

And Java configuration, my code for both dataSources

MyApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    ControllerConfig.class,
    PersistenceConfig.class,
    PlrIntegrationConfig.class,
    SecurityConfig.class
})
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

PersistenceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
                   basePackages = {"com.my.app.repository"})
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("minimum-idle", "8");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maximum-pool-size", "100");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("idle-timeout", "10000");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("connection-timeout", "10000");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("max-lifetime", "120000");
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {


        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.my.app.entity")
                .properties(additionalJpaProperties())
                .persistenceUnit("app")
                .build();
    }

    private Map<String, ?> additionalJpaProperties() {
        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql"));
        return jpaProperties;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider(){
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

PlrIntegrationConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = {
    "com.my.app.integration.plr.job",
})
@Import({PlrIntegrationPersistenceConfig.class})
public class PlrIntegrationConfig {
}
```

PlrIntegrationPersistenceConfig.class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "plrInEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "plrInTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.my.app.integration.plr.persistence.repository"})
@Configuration
public class PlrIntegrationPersistenceConfig {

    @Value("${pqa.integration.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;
    @Value("${pqa.integration.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${pqa.integration.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${pqa.integration.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean(name = "plrInDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("minimum-idle", "8");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maximum-pool-size", "100");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("idle-timeout", "10000");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("connection-timeout", "10000");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("max-lifetime", "120000");
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "plrInEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean plrInEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                            @Qualifier("plrInDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean plrInEMFBean = builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.my.app.integration.plr.persistence.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("plrIn")
                .build();
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
        plrInEMFBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return plrInEMFBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "plrInTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager plrInTransactionManager(@Qualifier("plrInEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory plrInEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(plrInEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
FIXED, was neccessary to add

> config.setInitializationFailTimeout(-1L);

in secondDataSource configuration

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, was neccessary to add

> config.setInitializationFailTimeout(-1L);

in secondDataSource configuration